# calculate Image Pixels

Tags: image, opencv

All images have pixels(x,y)

1. I want to , know how to count the x and y pixels in the image
2. the no of pixels in the image

any one help me to do that using opencv c++

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gnosophilon pointed out, if your image is an opencv IplImage, then you have direct access to the number of pixels in your image.

```
int nImageType = CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR;
IplImage *pImage = cvLoadImage("myImage.bmp", nImageType); 

int nNumberOfPixelInImage = pImage->imageSize;
```

or alternately you could do this:

```
int nNumberOfPixelInImage = pImage->width * pImage->height;
```

If you look at the documentation for the IplImage structure you will find lots of information about the image.

But note that the structure element "pImage->nSize"  is NOT what you are apparently looking for--that is the size of the structure itself not the image.

Answer (score 1):

If your image is an `IplImage`, it will have attributes `width` and `height`, corresponding to the number of pixels in x and y direction, respectively.

Comment: Thanks,

but i want to know how to count P(x,y) pixels values in the image

Comment: @Mostafa What do you mean by this? Can your clarify, please?

Comment: i want to count x , y pixels coordinate value in image

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good tutorial for all your basic opencv questions such as finding width,height: http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html